# Convert comma separated binary string to byte[] for Registry insertion

Tags: c#, string, binary

This is really getting the better of me. I need to convert this:

```
string data = "4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,100,58,82,80,162,77,200,183,178,32"
```

into a byte array so that I can use it here:

```
polKey.SetValue("Blob", data, RegistryValueKind.Binary);
```

I've tried `data.Split(',')` to split it into an array and use that, but I can't get my head around it.

Comment: You mean that the first byte is 4, the second is 0, etc.?

Comment: I guess you could do that using LINQ: `data.Split(',').Cast<Byte>().ToArray();`

Comment: @Logerfo casting isn't going to work.  You have to parse the values, so instead of `.Cast<Byte>()` you need `.Select(byte.Parse)`.

Comment: @juharr you're right, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your byte array needs the *parsed* values (e.g. 4, 0, 1, 100, etc.) and not the ASCII values of each string.

First convert to an array of strings:

```
string[] strings = data.Split(',');
```

then convert each string to a byte:

```
byte[] bytes = strings.Select(s => byte.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq

```
string data = "4,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,16,0,0,0,100,58,82,80,162,77,200,183,178,32";
var buf = data.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
              .Select(x => byte.Parse(x))
              .ToArray();
```

A regex solution is also possible

```
var buf = Regex.Matches(data,@"\d+").Cast<Match>()
               .Select(x => byte.Parse(x.Value))
               .ToArray();
```